# When did C# get explicit interface implementation?

Tags: c#

When did C# get explicit interface implementation? Was this in version 1 or was it added later?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This feature has always existed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

It existed in the first public release of the C# language.